# Creating folders inside LocalLow through Installer

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, installation

I am developing deployment project for Vista. In Vista inside AppData folder there are Local, LocalLow and Roaming folders. What I want from installer is to create folder 'Data' inside LocalLow folder and put there file data.xml (AppData\LocalLow\Data\data.xml). Installer should make this operation for **all existing user accounts**.
How can I achieve this?

This is a screenshot of setup project('Data' folder configuration) which is not working:
[image]

Attached example creates the following path: \AppData\Roaming\LocalLow\Data\data.xml

Comment: I think you neither can do this using VS deployment project nor you should.

Comment: Agreed with Igor.  This is what Isolated Storage is for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I think a much better approach is to store the xml file in the application's install directory, then, when the application starts up, copy the file to the appropriate directory.

The primary issue is this: what if a user that wasn't on the machine when it was installed launches the application?

Since your installer didn't copy the file to their directory (because it didn't exist), your application would either have to do something or fail anyway.